# Concatenate values of records with same ID | Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to transform a table that looks like this:

```
ID    |  Year  |  Code
----------------------
1     |  2020  |    a
1     |  2019  |    b
1     |  2018  |    c
2     |  2019  |    d
2     |  2018  |    e
2     |  2017  |    f
3     |  2020  |    g
3     |  2018  |    h
```

to a table with a 'Sequence' column that includes a concatenation of the 'Year' values of all records with the same 'ID' under it, plus the current 'Code'.

The final table should look like this:

```
ID    |  Year  |  Code  | Sequence
------------------------------------------
1     |  2020  |    a   | 2018x2019x2020_a
1     |  2019  |    b   | 2018x2019_b
1     |  2018  |    c   | 2018_c
2     |  2019  |    d   | 2017x2018x2019_d
2     |  2018  |    e   | 2017x2018_e
2     |  2017  |    f   | 2017_f
3     |  2020  |    g   | 2018x2020_g
3     |  2018  |    h   | 2018_h
```

Currently, I have this code that concatenates all of the 'Year' values with the same 'ID' but I want it to include only records below the current record. I can't figure out how to do it.

```
df['Sequence'] = (df.astype({'Year': str})
                    .groupby('ID')['Year']
                    .transform(lambda x: 'x'.join(x[::-1]))
                    .add('_' + df['Code'].astype(str)))
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try groupby with cumsum() of lists like this:

**Sample:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {1: '1', 2: '1', 3: '1', 4: '2', 5: '2', 6: '2', 7: '3', 8: '3'}, 'Year': {1: 2020.0,  2: 2019.0,  3: 2018.0,  4: 2019.0,  5: 2018.0,  6: 2017.0,  7: 2020.0,  8: 2018.0}, 'Code': {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h'}})
```

**Code:**

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Year'], ascending=True)
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(int).astype(str)
df['Sequence'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Year'].apply(lambda x: x.map(lambda x: [x]).cumsum()).str.join('x') + '_' + df['Code']
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Year'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Comment: @JanValušek Glad I could help, Happy coding!